# What order does Wikidata's SPARQL endpoint use when there is no `ORDER BY` clause?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

The following query loads twenty cities from Wikidata, together with the country or state of which they are the capital:

```
SELECT ?item ?capitalOf WHERE {
 ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515.
 OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P1376 ?capitalOf. }
}
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

The results are Q60 (New York), Q62 (San Francisco), Q64 (Berlin), Q84 (London) etc.

Now set the `OFFSET` parameter to `1`, and you get the same list starting at Q62. Index 0 is omitted, as expected. With `OFFSET` set to `2`, you get the same list starting at index 2.

However, sometimes you get a completely different result. For example, I just got the list `Q2807, Q2861, Q2900 ...` when using `OFFSET 70`, but this list didn't overlap the list from `OFFSET 60`. It seems that there is some randomness in the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` query clauses.

**What is the default sort order of SPARQL results?**

The reason I'm asking: We are using some queries that need to be loaded with `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY`, because the number of results is so big. Moreover, these queries run into timeouts when using an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as with SQL, there is no default sort order of SPARQL results.

The SPARQL processor is allowed to return solutions in *any* order, which may (but typically will not) vary with each execution of the query.

The only way to be certain of the order of solutions is to include an `ORDER BY` clause.

When running expensive (e.g., long-running) queries, the best way to address this is to set up your own local repository/processor/endpoint, instead of using a public endpoint, such as that at wikidata.org.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. However, setting up your own endpoint will be very time-intensive, won't it? See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536930/can-i-run-sparql-queries-against-a-wikidata-dump-locally). Or is there a faster way?

Comment: Sorry, the linked question was deleted recently. There was someone saying that it can take weeks to do a data import locally.

Comment: @cheesusSOstopharmingMonica If you give your DBMS enough resource (RAM and disk, primarily), properly tune it to use those, and optimize your bulk-load routine, a local data load can be (relatively) quick. We (OpenLink Software) [loaded the full 2019-06-10  Wikidata dump (383 GB in Turtle) into Virtuoso in about 43 hours](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-stlTC_WJmMU3xA_NxA1tSLHw6_sbpjff-5OITtrbFw/edit#gid=1799898600&range=C91). We expect to ship an AWS AMI (PAGO pricing model) with a preconfigured Virtuoso instance, pre-populated with Wikidata, in the next few months, maybe weeks.

Comment: @cheesusSOstopharmingMonica - I meant also to say, you can try your queries on our test instance, as [seen here](https://wikidata.demo.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2F&qtxt=SELECT+%3Fitem+%3FcapitalOf%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++%3Fitem++wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279*++wd%3AQ515+.%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fitem++wdt%3AP1376+%3FcapitalOf.+%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3Fitem+%3FcapitalOf%0D%0ALIMIT+20%0D%0AOFFSET+0&format=text%2Fx-html%2Btr&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+)

Comment: This looks very promising. Is Blazegraph used as the backend?

Comment: The linked query (without the `LIMIT` clause) yields 57'371 results on your test instance, whereas query.wikidata.org yields only 48'227. Do you happen to see the difference? Is it the software or the loaded data dump that's different?

Comment: @cheesusSOstopharmingMonica The backend of the instance I linked above is Virtuoso (not Blazegraph), as I said in that link. I presume the difference in result count is due to changes in the underlying data (as our test instance's content was loaded from their June 10 dump).

Comment: This is great, thank you. Of course, you said it was Virtuoso. Do you have a newsletter available, so we can get notified about the availability of that perpopulated AWS instance?

Comment: @cheesusSOstopharmingMonica - [OpenLink Software newsletter subscription page](https://upscri.be/4b9872/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an error, "Oops! Something went wrong", when trying to subscribe.

Comment: @cheesusSOstopharmingMonica - Can you try going to any of the articles in [our Virtuoso-focused space on Medium](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog), and filling out the (very similar) form at the end of the article?

Comment: Did that. upscri.be answers with "Hmm... Something went wrong".

Comment: Do you have a schedule for the upcoming AWS AMI with pre-populated Wikidata data? Btw, the newsletter subscribe page is working again, I'm now subscribed.